# How to determine file types in Android

Tags: android, file-type

What is the best way to determine a file type in Android?

I want to check if the given file is an image, a music file, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Include some `mime.types` files in your assets folder (for example from /etc/mime.types).
2. Include `activation.jar` (from JAF) in your build path.
3. Use something like this:

   ```
   try {
       MimetypesFileTypeMap mftm = 
           new MimetypesFileTypeMap(getAssets().open("mime.types"));
       FileTypeMap.setDefaultFileTypeMap(mftm);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
4. Then use `FileDataSource.getContentType()` to obtain file types.

Comment: what is mime.types. Is this an XML file where ourselves define the type for each file extension?

Comment: It's not XML, it's just plain text, you can find it on many Linux/Unix on /etc. Contains lines like: "application/andrew-inset   ez"

Answer (score 1):

A common way is by their extension only, or you can parse the header, but it should be too much slower and more complex for your apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getMimeType(String fileUrl) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
    final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    return (mimeType !=  null) ? mimeType : "unknown";
}
```